# How I can fixed error after compiling project?

Tags: angular

Everything used to work well. It was necessary to transfer the component to another directory.

I transferred the component, connected it everywhere, but now an error has appeared

```
//MyModule
import { MyComponent } from 'path'

const components = [
    MyComponent
]
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        ...components
]
})

//AppModule
imports: [
    MyModule
]
```

ERROR in : Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'my-component'.
1. If 'my-component' is an Angular component and it has 'readOnly' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
][readonly]="true" label="text" [control]="linkedContractInfoForm.g")
: Can't bind to 'control' since it isn't a known property of 'my-component'.

Comment: Is it the correct path (maybe try it with auto-import)? Have you tried adding your component to the module exports?

Comment: ofc its the correct path. Im using WebStorm

Comment: is it an entry component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether is it the correct path that you are added into every place where you are importing 'MyComponent'. Also, check-in the app.module.ts that the path is correctly added or not for 'MyComponent'.

Then add 'MyComponent' under 'declarations' Array in the app.module.ts.
Example:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyComponent} from './components/my/my.component'; //your component(add your component path here)

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
MyComponent  //your component
],

imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
AppRoutingModule
],

providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```